# deciding whether cw or acw rotation from gesture, 3 ordered sample points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

[image: explain problem]

user starts from A and moves to C though(via) B (sample points on screen) in unity3d. at this point, i have calculated angle (theta) which in both images is almost 45 deg(almost). problem is i wanted to conclude that in left image user intended CounterClockWise motion and in right image user intends clockwise rotation.
ahh, its really complicated than i imagined, please suggest.

currently unity code is like

```
    protected void calcAngles(){
    v1 = go2.position - go1.position;
    v2 = go3.position - go1.position;
    v3 = go3.position - go2.position;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle (v2, v1);
    Debug.Log ("angle:" + angle.ToString ());
    //float atan = Mathf.Atan2 (Vector3.Dot (v3, Vector3.Cross (v1, v2)), Vector3.Dot (v1, v2)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    //Debug.Log ("atan2:" + atan.ToString ());
}
```

any ideas.? psudo code.? huge thanks in advance. cheers,lala

Comment: If you aren't going to build a crowd simulator (because this is going to be a little heavy) you could use 2 helper transforms as child of A. they are at 0,0,0 position in local space. One is using **LookAt(B)** another is using **LookAt(C)**. Then you could just take the difference between their Y euler angles. This will tell you if you need to rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Comment: "crowd simulator" what are you referrring to, Nika ?

Comment: to get the direction from red to green is trivial.  it is simply red minus green.  LookAt is not relevant.  that is used to *actually twist* a `Transform`.  to simply get the direction, you merely subtract the positions and perhaps .normalize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **incredibly difficult** to do this.

This may help...

```
private float bestKnownXYCWAngleFromTo(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
// the best technology we have so far
    {
    a.z = 0f;
    b.z = 0f;

    float __angleCCW = Mathf.Atan2(b.y, b.x) - Mathf.Atan2(a.y, a.x);
    if ( __angleCCW < 0f ) __angleCCW += (2.0f * Mathf.PI);

    float __angleCWviaatan = (2.0f * Mathf.PI) - __angleCCW;
    __angleCWviaatan = __angleCWviaatan * (Mathf.Rad2Deg);

    if ( __angleCWviaatan >= 360.0 ) __angleCWviaatan = __angleCWviaatan-360.0f;

    return __angleCWviaatan;
    }
```

note that this is a 2D concept, modify as you need.

note that obviously "a" is just your (b-a) and "b" is just your (c-a)

---

Please note that ***true gesture recognition*** is a very advanced research field.  I encourage you to get one of the solutions out there,

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14458

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21660

which represent **literally dozens of engineer-years of effort**.  PDollar is great (that implementation is even free on the asset store!)

Comment: just wanted to mention huge thanks, and it really means a lot. such a detailed thought with references and main equation to decide.

Comment: just waiting for any more questions, buddy!!  you can flag to them here

Answer (score 0):

Uuuups. My answer from before was completely wrong. It seems that Vector3.Angle always gives a unsigned angle. But we need the sign to understand whether is rotating clockwise or counterclockwise.

Now, this piece of code will give you a SIGNED angle between your two vectors. The Normal argument should be the normal to the plane you want to consider.

```
   float SignedAngle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 normal){

        float angle = Vector3.Angle(from,to);
        float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(normal, Vector3.Cross(from,to)));
        float signed_angle = angle * sign;

        return signed_angle;
    }
```

Comment: no, Vector3.Angle always returns a positive angle less than 180 degrees.